# Question on Site Structuring

Tags: routes

In Drupal 7.x, is there a general rule on creating the page hierarchy? I'm porting over an old Joomla 1.x website to drupal, and the site index is pretty big with about 6 levels, and a lot of it resides on the main menu.

Would I create a static page (content), link it to the menu, and then create child static pages and link it to the submenu (as this is how I've started doing it) or is there a simpler way of doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, if you want a fixed hierarchy, placing nodes in a menu structure is the way to do it.

That said, 6 levels is a lot, so I doubt if it's really the best way for your users to find the content they're looking for. You could consider using [Views](http://drupal.org/project/views) to create lists (maybe with filters) of content.

Comment: What's saddening is the Joomla-to-Drupal module doesn't keep category/section names of the content, so I have to re-categorize the content or create taxonomy terms for them to organize them. =( such a headache.

Answer (score 1):

If your content is actually hierarchical, you can use [Views tree](http://drupal.org/project/views_tree) and forget about the menu system altogether.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Feeds](http://drupal.org/project/feeds) and [Feeds SQL](http://drupal.org/project/feeds_sql) to import the data automatically.

Comment: How does Feeds and Feeds SQL help with structuring the data?

Comment: you make content type you want the content to be imported to

Comment: Since this content is either already a node in my Drupal installation, or content on a Joomla site, how would I go about accomplishing this when the content is not being fed and I cannot create a CSV file with the content?

Comment: i am simply suggesting that if you need to get your joomla or any other content from other sql to drupal then these modules do the trick